# вопрос по кодировке java

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Здравствуйте,есть jsp страница в которой есть поле куда нужно вводить строку,передает это всё в сервлет который выводит это.Но если данные на русском языке,выводит ерунду.как исправить?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<html >
<body >
    <FORM action="testform" method=POST>
        <H3>
            Введи что-нибудь < INPUT type="text" name="Имя проекта"
                value="-задать!-">
        </H3>
        <INPUT type="submit" value="Принять"> <BR>
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

---

и сервлет

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name;
        String value;
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.print("<HTML lang=\"ru-Ru\"><HEAD>");
        writer.print("<TITLE>Результат</TITLE>");
        writer.print("</HEAD><BODY></BODY>");
        Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            name = (String)names.nextElement();
            value = request.getParameterValues(name)[0];
            writer.print("<H1>name = " + name + " value = " + value+"</H1>");
        }
        writer.print("< /HTML>");

}
```

Comment: В сервлете кодировку тоже неплохо б установить заголовком.

Comment: ответ с `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")` правильный, но я рекомендую вам прочитать про Filter

Comment: @iGreetYou будет сделано!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сервлете:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
```

Comment: спасибо,всё заработало)